# How to get the Last data from Database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to get a column of the last data in the database but so far, I am getting all the data in the database in an array.

This is my code;

```
public function NewID(){

    $adminid=Auth::user()->admin_id;//cooperative ID

    $newid = Member::select('member_id')->where('admin_id', '=',$adminid)->get();

    return View::make('admin.member.addmember')
            ->with('NewID', $newid);
}
```

I have updated the code to be this base on suggestions;

```
    public function NewID(){

    $adminid=Auth::user()->admin_id;//cooperative ID

    $newid = Member::select('member_id')->where('admin_id', '=',$adminid)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

    return View::make('admin.member.addmember')
            ->with('NewID', $newid);
}
```

and I am using a `For Loop` to display data on the view

```
  @foreach ($NewID as $NewIDs)

     {{$NewIDs->member_id}}
  @endforeach
```

My error is now `ErrorException:Trying to get property of non-object`

**Answer**

I finally got it to work

I used this instead

```
 public function NewID(){

    $adminid=Auth::user()->admin_id;//cooperative ID

    $newid = Member::select('member_id')->where('admin_id', '=',$adminid)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();

    return View::make('admin.member.addmember')
            ->with('NewID', $newid);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel select last row on database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549455/laravel-select-last-row-on-database-table)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins lemme check if that will help me, thanks all the same

Comment: If you are encountering specific errors after implementing the suggestion, please update your question with your new code and an explanation of the error or difficulty you are now encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work

I used this instead

```
 public function NewID(){

    $adminid=Auth::user()->admin_id;// ID

    $newid = Member::select('member_id')->where('admin_id', '=',$adminid)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();

  return View::make('admin.member.addmember')
        ->with('NewID', $newid);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a lot of things could be wrong, so what you should do is find the cause. In you view file, temporarily remove the `foreach` loop and replace it with `{{ dd($NewID) }}`. This will 'dump and die' the value of $NewID.

Additionally, I suggest you stick to variable naming conventions. Variables should start lowercase. Also it is confusing to call a collection of Members `NewID` and a single instance of a member `NewIDs`. Sticking to the convention helps you and others to read and debug your code.

Comment: Glad it's working. Would you mind sharing what was the issue so others can learn from it. Also, if my answer helped you out, I'd be grateful if you accept it as the correct answer.