# How do I order a relationship in Laravel?

Tags: orm, laravel-5

I saw this question in StackOverflow, but I could not answer it because it was mistakenly marked as duplicate.  However $user->posts is not the same as Posts::all().  So if you have User and Post, how do you sort the posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, answering my own question just to help out.  Note that calling posts as a var is different than calling posts as a method.  The var resolves to the query result, the method resolves to the query builder.

```
class User extends Model implements ... {
    public function posts(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
        }

    /*

    /**
     * $this->posts is already a collection after query
     */
    public function recentPosts($limit = 5){
    return $this->posts
        ->sortByDesc(function ($post){
            return $post->created_at;
        })->take($limit);
    }

    /**
     * $this->posts() is the query builder
     */
    public function latestPosts($limit = 5){
        return $this->posts()
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    }

}
```