# Have a way to just show the last item from my db, in a view with @foreach?

Tags: laravel

Have a way to just show the last item added on my db, to my home with @foreach?

```
@foreach(App\Models\Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get() as $post)
                                    <div class="fs-rp-item">
                                        <div class="entry-image">
                                            <!--<a href="#"><img src="/holy/images/blog/fs-thumb.jpg" alt="recent post"></a>-->
                                            <a href="#"><img src="/uploads/post/{{$post->id}}/image/{{$post->file_1}}" alt="recent post"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="entry-rp">
                                            <h4>
                                                <a href="#">{{$post->title}}</a>
                                            </h4>
                                            <p class="read-more">
                                                <a href="#">read the article</a>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Isn't already what you did?

Comment: Why would you iterate over a loop if you would like to display only the last item?

Comment: I have you considered using Laravel eloquent model to get last record on DB. It works like this Model ::all()->last() . Try this Post::all()->last() . You can check for more options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549455/select-last-row-in-the-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
App\Models\Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. To me it does not make sense to iterate over a loop in order to show just the last item.

Anyhow, this is the approach for doing so:

```
@foreach(App\Models\Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get() as $post)
     @if($loop->last)
         // the end of the loop is reached at this point
     @endif
@endforeach
```

A better approach would be to get the latest item from the post within your controller and pass that to the view, and print just its data:

```
use App\Models\Post; // at the top of your class

// your controller
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::latest()->first();
    return view('index', compact('post'));
}
```

Then in the view you just use the latest post for example:

```
<h4>
    <a href="#">{{$post->title}}</a>
</h4>
```