# How to get latest record based on one column in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to select rows based on one column which is customer_id. Now the situation is there is a column ccustomer_id in Invoices table.

Here is how I am getting it now

```
Invoice::where('payment_status',1)->get()
```

But problem with this query is if there are two invoices for customer it will get both invoice. I need only  latest one?

What will be query for that thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Last Row in the Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549455/select-last-row-in-the-table)

Comment: So you need single result from the query or one row per customer ?

Answer (score 2):

here is what you need to do

```
Invoice::where('payment_status',1)->order_by('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```