# Laravel API resources, get only the latest occurrence from a collection

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I am developing an api in laravel for an online course system. In this scheme I have a standard table for users, a table for courses and a pivot table that relates courses and users according to which they sign up for each course.

This last table also carries the events related to the progress of each user in the course, that is, Subscribed, Progress x%, Completed, Approved, so that each user can have multiple entries in the course_users table.

So far everything is clear and everything is fine, the point is that at a certain moment I need to return a json object with the information of the courses and pointed users, this can be clearly achieved using resource collection in the following way:

**CourseCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\CargoResource;

class CourseCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => CourseResource::collection($this->collection),
            'links' => [
                'self' => 'link-value',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**CourseResource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CourseResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title'=> $this->title,
            'description'=> $this->description,
            'price'=> $this->price,
            'users' => CourseUserResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('users'))
        ];
    }
}
```

**CourseUserResource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CourseUserResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'course_id'=> $this-> course_id,
            'user_id'=> $this->user_id,
            'event'=> $this->event,
            'event_date' => $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d')
        ];
    }
}
```

The problem to be solved is that with this scheme I obtain a collection of events for each user and course, but what I am needing is only the last event of each user, to know what their status is in relation to the course.

I am analyzing the option to perform the query by sql and then manually build the json object, but I would like to have a "laravel style" solution

Any ideas will be welcome!

[image: EER Diagram]

**Added Models & Controllers for clarification**

```
class Course extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'description',
        'course_category_id',
        'price',
        'published'
    ];

...

    public function history()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CourseUser::class, 'course_id', 'id')->latest();
    }

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published', 1);
    }

}
```

---

```
class CourseUser extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_id',
        'user_id',
        'event'
    ];

}
```

---

```
class SearchController extends ApiController
{

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $results = Course::with('history')
            ->published
            ->where('title', 'like', $request->filter['title'])
            ->where('description', 'like', $request->filter['description'])
            ->get();

        if (! count($results) > 0) {
            return $this->sendResponse(
                __('No results for your query.'),
                [
                    'code'=>204,
                    'message'=> __('There are no results for your search criteria.')
                ],
                204
            );
        }
        return new CourseCollection($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549612/4764353

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I think it's related to a normal selection in a controller and I need to perform something like that but in a resource, with additional group by constraint. Anyway I will read it in deep.

Comment: Think like this: any resource is like a mapper, it will format data to what you need/want to. So, if you need/want a rule on what data to use, you have to filter it before sending it to the resource, it is not the resource responsibility to "filter" this data, it's responsibility is to show the data the way you want. So please, could you share the controller or whoever is using this so we can help you with your query ?

Comment: Can you include the controller code where you load users and events?

Comment: I added the models and controllers to show how the data is gathered. If I only had to return the search results there would be no problem, but what I also need is that the list of results must indicate if the user who performs the search is already pointed to that course, and what is the last registered event (subscribed , started, advanced x%, completed, passed)