# How to get latest record in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the latest record from my database. But the methods I`ve found online all seem to be out of date. Is there anyway of doing this in laravel 9.

Old Code :

```
$picture = Auth::user()->files->groupBy('id')->latest->get();
$picture = Auth::user()->files->order_By('id','desc')->first->get();
$picture = Auth::user()->files->latest('id')->first();
```

Old versions of fixing this dont work as I`ve stated above

Comment: try `Model::latest()->first()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434222

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I get the error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist`

Comment: `Auth::user()->files->groupBy('id')->latest()->first()`

Comment: That gives me the same error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.`

Comment: oh, hmmm. yeah i think is like this - `files()`. if u specify the `()`, means u r doing the query. if u dont specify it, means u want to retrieve them (so it retrieves them and converts them into a collection). in this case u dont want to retrieve them yet, cuz u want to apply more queries

Comment: No that doesnt work  `$picture = Auth::user()->files->first();`  That code works for getting the first value. Is there not just a way to do ->last() instead of first?

Comment: u tried this way? `Auth::user()->files()->lastest()->first()`